# Novel about suppressed desires

Tags: story-identification

There's a YA novel I read in the mid-2000s that I've been looking for for years but was never able to find again.

The main character is possessed by a magical creature that makes her carry out all the dark desires she thought about doing but didn't actually want to do, like steal from an old man. I think she might also kill one of a pair of witches, and the remaining witch gains the power to use an invisible pair of hands.

The story ended with the main character helping the creature that possessed her die, and she came dangerously close to dying in the process.

Comment: I wonder if it's the same one as at https://www.nypl.org/blog/2017/11/22/finding-book-forgotten-title?page=6 with an orage cover, an female demon, a school trip, and a murder hallucination.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215760/terry-pratchett-book-with-a-lawyer-dragon-and-sheep (about the first book in the series)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A Hat Full Of Sky** by Terry Pratchett

This is the second of the Tiffany Aching stories in the Discworld series, the first is The Wee Free Men.

Tiffany is sent to learn "witching" from Miss Level, a witch who is one mind operating two bodies.  While staying with Miss Level, Tiffany Aching is possessed by a creature called a hiver.  While possessed, Tiffany kills one of Miss Level's bodies, but Miss Level remains able to use four hands simultaneously, just two of them are invisible.  While possessed she also steals from Mr Weavall in order to make some purchases to impress her wealthier peers, especially Annagramma.

Tiffany does assist the hiver to die in the end, and would have died herself (after some typically enjoyable conversation with Death) except for the intervention of Granny Weatherwax.

Comment: That's definitely it. Thank you!